# Solr with two different cores and single query

Tags: solr

I have two tables in RDBMS

**Table Strucutre**

*Table : tblUser*
            UserId
            AvatarURL

*Table : tblSchedule*

- Id
- UserId (ForeignKey)
- StartTime
- EndTime

**Scenario**

> There are total 100 users in tblUser table among them 20 users are
>   schedule for today. 10 users are for the 10 AM to 12 PM.  2 users are
>   for 1 PM to 4 PM and rest are 4 PM to 11:59 PM. I want to display 10
>   (reset based on pagging) users from the solr core     (there should be
>   two different cores one for tblUser and second for tblSchedule, this I
>   have to do for future reference)  Frist two records display based on
>   tblSchedule as per  the time reset will display which are not in
>   tblSchedule.      On second page again the first two records display
>   based on time reset will display based on their insetion.     In other
>   words order by should be done on schedule and UserId. I want to write
>   single query with faceting on other fields for these two cores.

Answer (score 2):

Solr data structures should be optimized for searching and may end up looking nothing like your original data structures. If the difference is very great, you may end up just getting the IDs out of Solr and matching them to the original database for getting the objects/relationships.

In your case, it may be worth keeping user information outside of Solr and focus on encoding and retrieving the right schedule document.

Also, with the latest Solr, [DateRangeField](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates) might be useful approach to keep start-end date range.